# How to replace tokens with pyspellchecker

Tags: python, xml, spell-checking

I have an XML file which contains a raw OCR output with a lot of typographical errors:

```
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xml:lang="fr" n="5419000" xml:id="cb30263946g">
  <teiHeader>
    <fileDesc>
      <titleStmt>
        <title>Les livres classiques de l'empire de la Chine</title>
        <author role="Auteur du texte" key="11909957">Confucius (0551?-0479? av. J.-C.)</author>
        <respStmt>
          <resp key="40">Annotateur</resp>
          <name key="12176450">Pluquet, François-André-Adrien (1716-1790)</name>
        </respStmt>
        <respStmt>
          <resp key="680">Traducteur</resp>
          <name key="16653645">Noël, François (1651-1729)</name>
        </respStmt>
      </titleStmt>
      <publicationStmt>
        <publisher>TGB (BnF – OBVIL)</publisher>
      </publicationStmt>
      <seriesStmt>
        <title level="s">Les livres classiques de l'empire de la Chine</title>
        <title level="a">Tome 2</title>
        <biblScope unit="volumes" n="6"/>
        <idno>cb30263946g</idno>
      </seriesStmt>
      <sourceDesc>
        <bibl>
          <idno>http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k54190001</idno>
          <publisher>Barrois aîné et Barrois jeune</publisher>
          <date when="1784">1784</date>
        </bibl>
      </sourceDesc>
    </fileDesc>
    <xenoData>
      <date>1784</date>
      <title>Les livres classiques de l'empire de la Chine — Tome 2</title>
      <dewey>950 - Histoire générale de l'Asie</dewey>
      <meta-data_comprehensiveness_score>0.67</meta-data_comprehensiveness_score>
      <authors>
        <author_1>
          <alpha_key>confucius</alpha_key>
          <age_at_publication>1233</age_at_publication>
          <last_name>Confucius</last_name>
          <key>11909957</key>
          <author>Confucius (0551?-0479? av. J.-C.)</author>
          <is_reconciliated>True</is_reconciliated>
          <death>0479</death>
          <role>Auteur du texte</role>
          <birth>0551</birth>
        </author_1>
      </authors>
    </xenoData>
  </teiHeader>
  <text>
    <body>
      <pb xml:id="PAG_00000001" n="" corresp="http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k54190001/f1.image"/>
      <pb xml:id="PAG_00000002" n="" corresp="http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k54190001/f2.image"/>
      <pb xml:id="PAG_00000003" n="" corresp="http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k54190001/f3.image"/>
      <pb xml:id="PAG_00000004" n="" corresp="http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k54190001/f4.image"/>
      <div>
        <head>Livres classiques</head>
        <p rend="left">
DE L’EMPIRE .
</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <head>De la chine.</head>
        <pb xml:id="PAG_00000005" n="" corresp="http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k54190001/f5.image"/>
        <pb xml:id="PAG_00000006" n="" corresp="http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k54190001/f6.image"/>
        <pb xml:id="PAG_00000007" n="" corresp="http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k54190001/f7.image"/>
        <pb xml:id="PAG_00000008" n="" corresp="http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k54190001/f8.image"/>
      </div>
      <div>
        <head>Observations</head>
        <p rend="left small">SUR</p>
        <p rend="center small">LES LIVRES CLASSIQUES</p>
        <p rend="center small">DE L’EMPIRE</p>
        <p rend="center small">DE LA CHINE.</p>
        <p rend="small">.LES Chinois ont deux sortes de
livres clafliques ou canoniques : les
Kings, ou les livres canoniques du
premier ordre ; &amp; les Ssée-chu, ou
livres canoniques dusecond ordre.</p>
        <p rend="small">Les Kings sont au nombre de
cinq ; l’Y-king, le Chu-king,lc
Chi-king, le Tchun-tfiou &amp; le Lild.</p>
        <p rend="left small">L’Y-king remonte à la plus haute
<hi rend="i">Tome II. a</hi></p>
        <p rend="left"><hi rend="i">'\</hi><pb xml:id="PAG_00000009" n="" corresp="http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k54190001/f9.image"/>ij O B S E K.VATI ON S.</p>
        <p rend="small">antiquité ; on l’attribue en grande
partie à Fo - hi : c’eft un ouvrage
qui, par le moyen des <hi rend="i">emblèmes</hi>,
explique ou repréfente la doétrine
des anciens temps fur les diverfes
opérations de la nature, fur les différents
états de la vie humaine, fur
les vertus &amp; fur les vices , fur
les sorts heureux ou malheureux.
Ainfi, par exemple, des montagnes
sous terre fignifîent l’humilité, &amp; la
difpolîtion ou la longueur de différentes
lignes combinées fervent à exprimer
les effets de cette vertu ( i).</p>
        <p rend="small">(i) Notice de l’Y-king, par M. Vifdeîau,
à la fin de la traduction du Chufcing.</p>
        <pb xml:id="PAG_00000010" n="" corresp="http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k54190001/f10.image"/>
        <p rend="left small">O B S E R VAT1 O N S. iij</p>
        <p rend="small">Le Chu-king efl: l’hiftoire des
premiers empereurs, relativement
à la morale &amp; à la politique, ou le
recueil de leurs principes fur la morale
&amp; fur le gouvernement.</p>
        <p rend="small">Le Chi-king efl: un recueil de
poéfies composées sous les règnes
de la troifieme race, &amp; dans lefquelles
on décrit les moeurs, les
coutumes-, les maximes des petits
rois qui gouvernoient les provinces
sous la dépendance de l’empereur
(i).</p>
      </div>
      <div>
        <head>Fin. (|\\ï:</head>
        <pb xml:id="PAG_00000276" n="" corresp="http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k54190001/f276.image"/>
        <pb xml:id="PAG_00000277" n="" corresp="http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k54190001/f277.image"/>
        <pb xml:id="PAG_00000278" n="" corresp="http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k54190001/f278.image"/>
      </div>
    </body>
  </text>
</TEI>
```

I am trying to modify it by replacing the incorrectly outputted words (e.g. `clafliques`) with the correct ones (`classiques`) contained in the French dictionary within the `pyspellchecker` library.

When I run this script:

```
import re
from spellchecker import SpellChecker

entry = "test.xml"
output = "test_out.xml"


# remove the xml tags

text = re.sub('<[^<]+>', "", open(entry).read()) 
with open(output, "w") as f:
    f.write(text)
    
    
# get the list of tokens   
    
my_file = open(output, "r")
content = my_file.read()
content_list = content.split('  ')


# remove multiple spaces    
 
text = re.sub('\s+',' ', open(output).read())


# set the French spell checker 

spell = SpellChecker(language='fr')
misspelled = spell.unknown(content_list)

correct = spell.correction(word)

# Python program to convert a list
# to string using join() function
    
# Function to convert  
def listToString(s): 
    
    # initialize an empty string
    str1 = " " 
    # return string  
    return (str1.join(misspelled))
    


# replace the incorrect words with the correct ones

with open(output, "r+") as f:
    for c in content_list:
        #f.write(c.replace('clafliques', 'classiques'))  
        f.write(c.replace(listToString(misspelled), listToString(correct)))

f.close()
```

the changes do not apply (it works when I run `f.write(c.replace('clafliques', 'classiques'))`, though).

How do I correct automatically all the incorrect words?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possible solution:

```
import re
from spellchecker import SpellChecker


entry = "test.xml"
output = "test_out.xml"


# remove multiple spaces
# text = re.sub('\s+',' ', open(entry).read())


# remove the xml tags
text = re.sub('<[^<]+>', "", open(entry).read())


# set the French spell corrector
content_list = text.split()
spell = SpellChecker(language='fr')
misspelled = spell.unknown(content_list)


# add the token '&amp;' to the dictionary of the correct words in order for that not to be corrected into 'camp'
spell.word_frequency.load_words(['&amp;'])
# spell.known(['&amp;'])  # the word {'&amp;'} is now in the dictionary of the correct words


for m in misspelled:
    corrected = spell.correction(m)
    # print(corrected)

    
# correct directly in the entry doc
with open(output, "w") as f:
    for m in misspelled:
        corrected = spell.correction(m)
        text = text.replace(m, spell.correction(m))
        # f.write(c.replace('clafliques', 'classiques'))
    f.write(text)
```